# How to loop through each subdirectory and get all files within subdirectory as group in Python?

Tags: python, python-os, file-search

I need to iterate through folders in a directory, one by one, and perform a function on the files within those folders as a group. Those files need to be passed together, with their respective folder name, into a function. Sometimes, the directories contain only one file, but many times they contain 2 or more. Also, some folders contain more folders that I need to extract the file paths within as a group.

For example, my file structure can look like this:

```
├── root_folder
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── subdir2
│   │   ├── file3.txt
│   ├── subdir3
│   │   ├── file4.txt
│   │   ├── file5.txt
│   │   ├── file6.txt
│   ├── subdir4
│   |   ├── subdir42
│   │   |   ├── file7.txt
│   │   ├── subdir43
│   │   |   ├── file8.txt
│   │   |   ├── file9.txt
```

I would like to get all files from each dir, and the directory name to pass into a function. Below are the desired results:

- `myfunc("file1.txt","file2.txt",subdir1)`
- `myfunc("file3.txt",subdir2)`
- `myfunc("file4.txt","file5.txt","file6.txt",subdir3)`
- `myfunc("file7.txt",subdir42)`
- `myfunc("file8.txt","file9.txt",subdir43)`

Simply put, I need to loop through each folder recursively, one by one, and use all files within the folder to pass into a function.

My current code only returns all the filepaths for each file, but like I said, I need to use them in groups (where each folder contains a group of files).

```py
indir = "C:/path/to/indir"
for path, directories, files in os.walk(indir):
     for file in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(path, file)
        print(fpath)
```

Comment: So you need to perform a function on all the files in subdir1 right? Also how do you want to perform your operation on subdir4? Is it gonna be all files under subdir4 or individual operations on all files under subdir42 and subdir43?

Comment: "My current code only returns all the filepaths for each file, but like I said, I need to use them in groups" - what does that mean? Exactly what should the result be, and how is that different from the result you get?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I edited my question to include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create some sort of a recursive function which you can use to traverse the directories and then return the list of non-directory files in a list that you can use to pass into a function

```
import os

def traverse_directory(path):
    content = []
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for sf in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, sf) 
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            content += traverse_directory(f)
        else:
            content.append(f)
    
    # pass all files with the folder into a function
    # function_call(content)

    return content
    
print(traverse_directory('./root_folder'))
# returns ['./root_folder/sudir4/subdir42/file7.txt', './root_folder/sudir4/subdir43/file8.txt', './root_folder/sudir4/subdir43/file9.txt', './root_folder/sudir3/file4.txt', './root_folder/sudir3/file5.txt', './root_folder/sudir3/file6.txt', './root_folder/sudir2/file3.txt', './root_folder/sudir1/file2.txt', './root_folder/sudir1/file1.txt']
```

Edit: Based on your update expected function calls, I think the similar approach I suggested above should work but instead of returning all files in subdirectories, it would just get all the non-directory files in the same directory and pass as argument for the function call

```
import os

# sample myfunc to print out the input files and directory
def myfunc(*args):
    files, dr = args[:-1], args[-1]
    print('myfunc:', files, dr)

def traverse_directory(path):
    content = []
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for sf in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, sf) 
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            traverse_directory(f)
        else:
            content.append(sf)
    
    if content:
        content.append(path.split('/')[-1])
        myfunc(*content)

traverse_directory('./root_folder')
```

Running your sample data structure above should give the following output

```
myfunc: ('file7.txt',) subdir42
myfunc: ('file8.txt', 'file9.txt') subdir43
myfunc: ('file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt') sudir3
myfunc: ('file3.txt',) sudir2
myfunc: ('file2.txt', 'file1.txt') sudir1
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, I would need to go through many different subfolders to do so. I would like to be able to provide the rood directory, and traverse through each sub directory and getting filenames within subdirectory (if no files in subdir, continue)

Comment: @uasdev I think the `traverse_directory` does recursively go through the directory but just want to confirm the issue with the answer is that the root directory doesn't included in the `myfunc` argument?